# Find duplicate records in a table using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am validating a table which has a transaction level data of an eCommerce site and find the exact errors.

I want your help to find duplicate records in a 50 column table on SQL Server.

Suppose my data is:

```
OrderNo shoppername amountpayed city Item       
1       Sam         10          A    Iphone
1       Sam         10          A    Iphone--->>Duplication to be detected
1       Sam         5           A    Ipod
2       John        20          B    Macbook
3       John        25          B    Macbookair
4       Jack        5           A    Ipod
```

Suppose I use the below query:

```
Select shoppername,count(*) as cnt
from dbo.sales
having count(*) > 1
group by shoppername
```

will return me

```
Sam  2
John 2
```

But I don't want to find duplicate just over 1 or 2 columns. I want to find the duplicate over all the columns together in my data. I want the result as:

```
1       Sam         10          A    Iphone
```

Answer (score 69):

```
with x as   (select  *,rn = row_number()
            over(PARTITION BY OrderNo,item  order by OrderNo)
            from    #temp1)

select * from x
where rn > 1
```

you can remove duplicates by replacing select statement by

```
delete x where rn > 1
```

Comment: Great. I knew about this in Oracle, but didn't know this was possible in SQL server too.

Comment: For anyone curious, this is how I would write it in Oracle: `with x as (select  t.*, row_number() over(PARTITION BY OrderNo, item order by OrderNo) as rn from t_dcf t) select * from x where rn > 1;`

Comment: deserves to be selected as answer!

Answer (score 45):

```
SELECT OrderNo, shoppername, amountPayed, city, item, count(*) as cnt
FROM dbo.sales
GROUP BY OrderNo, shoppername, amountPayed, city, item
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SQL> SELECT JOB,COUNT(JOB) FROM EMP GROUP BY JOB;

JOB       COUNT(JOB)
--------- ----------
ANALYST            2
CLERK              4
MANAGER            3
PRESIDENT          1
SALESMAN           4
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add all fields to the query and remember to add them to Group By as well.

```
Select shoppername, a, b, amountpayed, item, count(*) as cnt
from dbo.sales
group by shoppername, a, b, amountpayed, item
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: I have 50 fields. So is there no way by which without writing individually names of all the fields I can find out the duplicate records!!

Comment: Right click on the table, select: Script table as >> Select to >> New Query Editor Window. Now you've got your SELECT list, copy and paste that into your GROUP BY section.

Answer (score 3):

To get the list of multiple records use following command

```
select field1,field2,field3, count(*)
  from table_name
  group by field1,field2,field3
  having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
SELECT MAX(shoppername), COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM dbo.sales
GROUP BY CHECKSUM(*)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Read about the [CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) function first, as there can be duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with T1 AS
(
SELECT LASTNAME, COUNT(1) AS 'COUNT' FROM Employees GROUP BY LastName HAVING  COUNT(1) > 1
)
SELECT E.*,T1.[COUNT] FROM Employees E INNER JOIN T1 ON T1.LastName = E.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as (
select shoppername,count(shoppername)
              from sales
              having count(shoppername)>1
            group by shoppername)
select t.* from x,win_gp_pin1510 t
where x.shoppername=t.shoppername
order by t.shoppername
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I doubt that the result it not accurate? Seem like there are Three 'Sam' from the original table. But it is not critical to the question.

Then here we come for the question itself. Based on your table, the best way to show duplicate value is to use `count(*)` and `Group by` clause. The query would look like this

`SELECT OrderNo, shoppername, amountPayed, city, item, count(*) as RepeatTimes            FROM dbo.sales                                                                             GROUP BY OrderNo, shoppername, amountPayed, city, item                               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

The reason is that all columns together from your table uniquely identified each record, which means the records will be considered as duplicate only when all values from each column are exactly the same, also you want to show all fields for duplicate records, so the `group by` will not miss any column, otherwise yes because you can only `select` columns that participate in the 'group by' clause.

Now I would like to give you any example for `With...Row_Number()Over(...)`, which is using table expression together with Row_Number function.

Suppose you have a nearly same table but with one extra column called **Shipping Date**, and the value may change even the rest are the same. Here it is:

`OrderNo shoppername amountpayed city Item        Shipping Date

1       Sam         10          A    Iphone       2016-01-01
1       Sam         10          A    Iphone       2016-02-02 
1       Sam         5           A    Ipod         2016-03-03
2       John        20          B    Macbook      2016-04-04
3       John        25          B    Macbookair   2016-05-05
4       Jack        5           A    Ipod         2016-06-06`

Notice that row# 2 is not a duplicate one if you still take all columns as a unit. But what if you want to treat them as duplicate as well in this case? You should use `With...Row_Number()Over(...)`, and the query would look like this:

`WITH TABLEEXPRESSION 
AS
(SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo, shoppername, amountPayed, city, item ORDER BY [Shipping Date] as Identifier) --if you consider the one with late shipping date as the duplicate
FROM dbo.sales)
SELECT * FROM TABLEEXPRESSION
WHERE Identifier !=1 --or use '>1'`

The above query will give result together with Shipping Date, for example:

`OrderNo shoppername amountpayed city Item        Shipping Date   Identifier
1       Sam         10          A    Iphone       2016-02-02          2`

Note this one is different from the one with 2016-01-01, and the reason why 2016-02-02 has been filtered out is `PARTITION BY OrderNo, shoppername, amountPayed, city, item ORDER BY [Shipping Date] as Identifier`, and Shipping Date is NOT one of the column that need to be took care of for duplicate records, which means the one with 2016-02-02 still could be a perfect result for your question.

Now summarize it little bit, using `count(*)` and `Group by` clause together is the best choice when you only want to show all columns from `Group by`clause as the result, otherwise you will miss the columns that do not participate in `group by`.

While For `With...Row_Number()Over(...)`, it is suitable in every scenario that you want to find duplicate records, however, it is little bit complicated to write the query and little bit over engineered compared to the former one.

**If your purpose is to delete duplicate records from table, you have to use the later `WITH...ROW_NUMBER()OVER(...)...DELETE FROM...WHERE`** one.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below methods to find the output

```
 with Ctec AS
 (
select *,Row_number() over(partition by name order by Name)Rnk
 from Table_A
)
select  Name from ctec
where rnk>1

select name from Table_A
 group by name
 having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score -2):

Select *
from dbo.sales
group by shoppername
having(count(Item) > 1)

Comment: That will **not** work. You will get an `Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause` error

Answer (score -2):

Select EventID,count(*) as cnt
from dbo.EventInstances 
group by EventID
having count(*) > 1

Answer (score -2):

The following is running code:

```
SELECT abnno, COUNT(abnno)
FROM tbl_Name
GROUP BY abnno
HAVING ( COUNT(abnno) > 1 )
```

Comment: Please include proper formatting in your answer, and also explain what this does to make it clearer.