# How can I find duplicate rows If I can't use ROW_NUMBER() in WHERE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query gets rows that are duplicates. I will be using this query to update references to the duplicates before I delete them.

```
SELECT TOP 350000 itmopt_pk, item_fk, option_fk,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY item_fk, option_fk ORDER BY item_fk ASC, option_fk ASC) AS RN
FROM item_options
WHERE RN > 1
GROUP BY itmopt_pk, item_fk, option_fk
ORDER BY RN DESC
```

The line `AND RN > 1` does not work and gives me `Invalid column name 'RN'`.

Trying to use `AND ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY item_fk, option_fk ORDER BY item_fk ASC, option_fk ASC) > 1` gives me `Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses`

I am using sqlsrv.

How can I return only rows where `RN > 1`?

Comment: You can't reference an expression in the `SELECT` in the `WHERE`, as the `WHERE` is processed before hand ([Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)). I would post a answer, but your query is further confused. Why do you have  a `GROUP BY` and no aggregation? Seems like an XY question; what is the *real* problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @Larnu I'm trying to get all rows that are duplicates, except for one (the one where RN is equal to 1), a duplicate being rows where item_fk and option_fk being the same.

Comment: @Goose you should mention that in the title itself. Duplicates are a common problem. Someone reading this question though would have to guess what the question is

Comment: @Goose and `GROUP BY` isn't needed. In fact, it would force you to aggregate the `RN` column. Looks like you tried to use both the GROUP BY and ROW_NUMBER techniques in the same query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get the T-SQL code to find duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222581/how-get-the-t-sql-code-to-find-duplicates)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate records in a table using SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849846/find-duplicate-records-in-a-table-using-sql-server)

Comment: Another way to do this is to use the group by with a having clause as in HAVING COUNT(1) > 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What part of the message do you not understand?  Window functions are not allowed in a `where`.  Neither are column aliases defined in the corresponding `SELECT`.  Use a subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 350000 itmopt_pk, item_fk, option_fk
FROM (SELECT itmopt_pk, item_fk, option_fk,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_fk, option_fk ORDER BY item_fk ASC, option_fk ASC) AS RN
      FROM item_options
     ) io
WHERE RN > 1
GROUP BY itmopt_pk, item_fk, option_fk
ORDER BY RN DESC;
```

This query seems strange.  I wonder if there is another way to express what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use column alias and Window functions in `WHERE` clause. You can use CTE or Subquery.

**Option1:** Common Table Expression:

```
WITH cte_query AS 
(
SELECT itmopt_pk, item_fk, option_fk,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY item_fk, option_fk ORDER BY item_fk ASC, option_fk ASC) AS RN
FROM item_options
GROUP BY itmopt_pk, item_fk, option_fk
)
SELECT itmopt_pk, item_fk, option_fk, RN
FROM cte_query
WHERE RN > 1
```

**Option2:** Subquery:

```
SELECT itmopt_pk, item_fk, option_fk, RN
FROM 
(
SELECT  itmopt_pk, item_fk, option_fk,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY item_fk, option_fk ORDER BY item_fk ASC, option_fk ASC) AS RN
FROM item_options
GROUP BY itmopt_pk, item_fk, option_fk
) A
WHERE RN > 1
```